# Is it possible to add an image icon to FCM notification in android / iOS?

Tags: java, android, spring, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to add an image as icon in the notification tray using the java firebase API? I have a spring boot backend and this is how I build the AndroidConfig:

```
    private AndroidConfig getAndroidConfig(String topic) {
        return AndroidConfig.builder()
            .putData("image", "url-to-image")
            .setTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(2).toMillis()).setCollapseKey(topic)
            .setPriority(AndroidConfig.Priority.HIGH)
            .setNotification(AndroidNotification.builder().setSound("default")
                .setColor("#FFFF00").setTag(topic).build()).build();
    }
```

but there is no image here in the notification tray:

[image]

Is it even possible to do this with the java API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `AndroidNotification.builder` it has a `setImage` method (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/AndroidNotification.Builder.html#setImage(java.lang.String) that should do the trick.

I've only created FCM notifications in node, but the notification builder looks similar to the payload I send in node to include images.

Comment: Hm you are right about the documentation but I don't have a setter like that in the builder in my code: https://imgur.com/a/fxLHFjU

Comment: What version of `firebase-admin` and `firebase-messaging`? 

Just created quick proj with latest dependencies: https://imgur.com/a/OMyeQcH

Comment: I bumped it up from `6.8` to `6.12` and now I also have it, thank you! :)